# Backbone model has url in id attribute

Tags: backbone.js

I am not sure if this is the way its supposed to be, but when debugging my backbone application I realized that my models have the url to the API in their ID attribute such as:

```
    App.houseCollection.models[0]
       Object
        _callbacks: Object
        _escapedAttributes: Object
        _pending: Object
        _previousAttributes: Object
        _silent: Object
        attributes: Object
        changed: Object
        cid: "c4"
        collection: Object
        id: "/api/v1/post/4/"
        __proto__: Object
```

I have a route that needs to access a model in the collection by the ID, i.e. just the numeric ID, in this example `id = 4`

Doing `App.houseCollection.get('/api/v1/post/4/')` works, but I want to be able to do `App.houseCollection.get(4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your server is returning the `id` as a URL rather than simply a number. Either fix your server or add a [`parse` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) to your model to clean up the `id`:

```
parse: function(response) {
    var matches;
    if(response.id
    && (matches = response.id.match(/\/(\d+)\/$/)))
        response.id = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
    return response;
}
```

You might want to adjust the regex of course.